# Protecting a page in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication

I come from the world of PHP and I'm struggling to grasp the concepts of NodeJS in terms of how to build the server and the different pages to serve.

I have an HTML page (`secret.html`) that I want to only be accessible once the user has authenticated themselves.

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if(authenticate(res.body.username, res.body.password)) {
        // User is now authenticated
        return res.redirect("/secret.html");
    } else {
        // Incorrect password - bring back to login page
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

In a way this works because both redirections behave the way I expect them to based on whether the user credentials are properly authenticated. However my problem with this is that the `secret.html` page isn't really protected by user authentication. I could just type on my browser `localhost/secret.html` and I get the contents as if I was properly authenticated.

How do I protect this page and make it so that only authenticated users get access to the page? What is the best practice for a NodeJS app when it comes to things like this?

Comment: what is /secret.html? a route? if so then add a checkAuthenticate middleware before entering it (which checks tokens or session which authenticate set or responded with), if its express.static then place a middleware in front for that file

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm not sure if it's a route in the world of NodeJS, it's just an HTML page on my `public` directory. Like I said, I'm still unfamiliar with how to build a NodeJS app.

Comment: btw, NodeJS is the language, what your using is a framework ([express](https://expressjs.com/)), you should probably look into learning https://www.passportjs.org/ as your eventually be using it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I looked at a tutorial earlier and there was a mention of passportjs but that looked like it uses third-party services like Google or Apple. That's not what I want.

Comment: it supports normal local https://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/ in your code what is `authenticate`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah I just saw that after I sent my last comment. Looks like I can use that then. `authenticate()` is not defined, I just replaced it for my very simplistic `req.body.password == process.env.ACCESS_CODE` - this is like a playground app as I am still learning NodeJS.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you provide a simple example for using passportjs to put my `secret.html` behind it then?

Comment: if your going to manually do things without using libs etc then you need to at least use sessions else you will need to send username and password on every request, login and then do something, there is lots or examples out there [example express login using sessions](https://www.google.com/search?q=example+express+login+using+sessions) , [example express login using passportjs](https://www.google.com/search?q=example+express+login+using+passportjs)